# how to use the variables from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, external-tools

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin (Eclipse preferencePage), and I need to know how to use the variables from eclipse (workspace_loc ,project_loc,.... ), because my path on the preference page will be set with them.
(that's my first question, let me know if you no understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IStringVariableManager` interface to access the manager for these variables:

```java
IStringVariableManager manager = VariablesPlugin.getDefault().getStringVariableManager();
```

You will need to add the `org.eclipse.core.variables` plugin to your plugin's dependencies.

The interface has various methods for accessing expressions containing variables, one of the main ones is:

```java
public String performStringSubstitution(String expression, boolean reportUndefinedVariables) throws CoreException;
```

You can pass this a string containing things like `${workspace_loc}` and it returns the resolved result.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 , the method works, but i still can't set the label with path solve.My code is below and i'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, iḿ still learn how to make something here.
And the new question is: "PropertyChangeListener validation".Thanks for the tips